# How to pass particular property to all child components in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-functional-component

I am absolute beginner in react. I have to pass particular property to all the components inside the div without passing them into individual,
For Example, Instead of doing this:

```
 function App() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Component1 props = {propObject}/>
        <Component2 props = {propObject}/>
        <Component3 props = {propObject}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

How can I achieve something like this? :

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div props={propObject}>
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
      <Component3 />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you can create 1 component that includes three or more of your components then pass data to main components throw props

Comment: Use React Context to share one or multiple states across all component.

Comment: use Context API

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

provides a way to share values to child components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree.

You need to import `React.context` from `react`

**syntax:**

```js
// context.js

import React, { createContext } from "react"

export const MyContext = React.createContext(null);
```

Now You need to create a provider of this context, to pass the current context value to the tree below. So you need to wrap all of your `child component` by the `React.Provider`.

**syntax:**

```js
// MainComponent.js
import { MyContext } from "./context"
import { ChildComponent1, ChildComponent2, ChildComponent3 } from "./childcomponent" 

const MainComponent = () => {
  const myObject = {name: "John"}

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider props={myObject}>
      <ChildComponent1 />
      <ChildComponent2 />
      <ChildComponent3 />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Now all the child component of this `MainComponent` has access of this `props` value which is provided by `MyContext.Provider`. Now you can simply get that values to your child components.

**syntax:**

```js
// childcomponent.js
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { MyContext } from "./context"

export const ChilcComponent1 = () => {
  const props = useContext(MyContext)
  return (
    <p>
      My name is: {props?.key}
    </p>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from ThemeProvider:

```
function App() {
      return (
        <ThemeProvider props = {propObject}>
          <Component1 />
          <Component2 />
          <Component3 />
        </ThemeProvider >
      );
    }
```

Comment: where do `ThemeProvider` come from? I don't think react provide that

Comment: @Andara I have seen that used here: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced